# My armature is not controlling my model

Tags: armature

I have made my first model of an arm and a hand, but when I made an armature for it, it didn't work. I didn't paint any weights because I used automatic weights. I parent the model to the armature, select automatic weights and then nothing happens. It loads and when it's done, moving the armatures  doesn't move the object. This is my first time doing it and I don't know anything other than making the armatures and sculpting the arm.

Comment: hello, it's hard to tell, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Just to be sure: You must be in *Pose* mode to test the rig, not in *Edit* mode. You're in *Pose* mode, right?

Comment: Is the armature symmetrical?

Comment: I've shared the file,  I was in pose mode not in edit mode and the armature is not symmetrical. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: If ypu have uploaded your file to pasteall.org to share it you need to post here the link that you see after the upload. Pasteall is an external site and is not affiliated to BSE.